# Integrate multiple (5) wcf services through one global integration wcf service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, service, integration

I'm working on an integration plan, to integrate 5 web services (WCF) through one global service that can serve as a service hub.

We have 1 service for each transactional core system, we have 5 systems, 5 web services, those web service work as a point of inbound, in our case, we need to control any kind of entry to those cores, store all data into one repository and work as a repository of distribution and data validation.

Our problem is:

- Each system/service works with same entities (client, address, agent, etc.), but, we don't have the same contracts (fields) on those systems/services.
- We don't have the ability of change all of those contracts, we need to implement a solution that fit our needs without change anything on those services.

What we tried:

- We created new DataContract and ServiceContract for the new integration service, to return an unique structure of each entity that provide all fields contained in all of those system contracts.
- We developed a new structure based on services load balancing and high-availability to provide the best performance experience to those systems that need to send information through WCF services.
- We implemented a namespace structure that fits for all endpoint and core system, separating all call to them in web services separately (this is just in case we need to call a web service separately that has been queued and has not been processed yet).
- We created a queue logic and business rules to manage those entries in that queue.

**Any help or opinion based in your expertise?**

Comment: You talked about queuing, does that mean you are using WCF queued transports?

Comment: No, we use a sql table to manage queue.